# Change visibility of UWP application while recording

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, xbox

I am trying to create an UWP Xaml application that has similar properties as Xbox Bar. I need my application to be not visible when recorded and rendered using screen recorder or captured using screen capture, but be running in the foreground.

I searched for similar application or source code, but unfortunately could not find and reference.

IDE - Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Change visibility of UWP application while recording

Sure, derive the testing, you could minimize recording app after recoding start. And here is [blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/16/new-ways-to-do-screen-capture/) you could refer to make record app. For minimize the app you could place the following code in [line 70](https://github.com/robmikh/SimpleRecorder/blob/master/CaptureEncoder/CaptureFrameWait.cs#L70) .

```
await Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(async (s) =>
                {
                    IList<AppDiagnosticInfo> infos = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoForAppAsync();
                    IList<AppResourceGroupInfo> resourceInfos = infos[0].GetResourceGroups();
                    await resourceInfos[0].StartSuspendAsync();
                });
```